# IF "OR" multiple conditions

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a standard 2x2 table

```
      Yes   No
Yes    a    b
No     c    d
```

I want to create a condition whereby IF(a or b or c or d = 0) then 0.5 is added on to each of the cells a,b,c,d.

I have tried this:

```
  if(a && b && c && d == 0){
    a=a+0.5, b=b+0.5, c=c+0.5, d=d+0.5
  }
```

But I am getting an error saying

```
Error: unexpected ',' in:
"if(a && b && c && d== 0){
a=a+0.5,"
```

i.e. I don't think it is letting me put multiple things to execute.

Also I don't think that the `&&` is right between each of the letters as I believe that means IF(a and b and ...)

UPDATE TO QUESTION:

I have another related question.

If I have say a set of say n tables, all in the format:

```
      Yes   No
Yes    a    b
No     c    d
```

and if one of the a,b,c or d in any of the n tables is equal to zero then 0.5 is added on to each of the a,b,c,d for all of the n tables. How would I do that?

My list looks like the following:

```
    n11   n12  n21   n22
1   188  1157  173  1168
2     2   201    1   101
3   369  2280  354  2289
4     1    61    0    61
5  1306 16870 1333 16773
6     4    81    3    79
7     6   117    5   118
8    19   334   15   318
9     1    49    0    48
10    0    36    1    33
11    2   114    3   113
12   13   433   37   696
13    1    64    0    65
14    4   157    1   160
15    1    42    0    43
16    1   150    5   146
17    7  1124   10  1117
18    2    78    2    77
```

and what I am trying to say is that if any of the aspects of the cells of the table are 0, then I want 0.5 to be added on to every cell.

Comment: For the update you could use a while loop over the table to see if one value is 0, then update all tables with a `for` loop over all tables (or put the tables in a list and use `lapply`).

Comment: I have amended my function so that I now get a list of each of the a,b,c,d for each of the tables. I have looked at the HELP for lapply but am unsure as to how I can use this here. Sorry I am relatively new to R and still struggling!

Comment: Can you precise what your list looks like in your question, my proposition was to have a list `matList` such as `matList[[some_index]]` is one of your table.

Comment: for the update `set.seed(1); f <- function(x) sample(c('No','Yes'), 5, replace = TRUE); l <- lapply(1:10, function(x) table(f(), f(), exclude = 'no')); lapply(l, function(x) if (any(x == 0)) x + .5 else x)`

Comment: @Math I have added the data which I am currently working with to the question to explain what form it comes in. I am wanting to incorporate into a function so that it will work with any data set, not just this one, i.e. there could be a data set with just 10 entries and if none of these entries were 0 then 0.5 would not be added

Comment: Under this form, use R high level functions to do it in one line `if (any(my_list==0)) { my_list = my_list + 0.5 }`

Comment: @Math In that case, is my_list a data frame? I have tried doing my_list=data.frame(n11,n12,n21,n22) and then copying your `if (any(my_list==0)) { my_list = my_list + 0.5 }` but that doesn't add 0.5 on to any of the cells

Comment: It works on data.frame as well. Can you post what you did and the result ?

Comment: Thanks so much, I have finally got it to work!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In R you can't use `,` to separate line, but you can use `;`.

Also, the way you are doing considers `a,b and c` are boolean (`TRUE/FALSE`), which is not the case as they are numbers. Your condition should be :

```
if (a == 0 || b == 0 || c == 0 || d == 0)
```

Note that your code will run nevertheless, even if `a,b and c` are not boolean since they are numbers and there is an equivalence between `FALSE` and `a == 0`. This means you could also write your condition as :

```
if (!a || !b || !c || !d)
```

For the UPDATE, I consider `matList` is the list of matrices :

```
for (ii in  1:length(matList())) {
    if (any(matList[[ii]] == 0)) {  
        matList = lapply(matList, function(X){X+0.5})
        break # Exit the for loop
    }
}
```

`lapply` applies `mat + 0.5` (i.e + 0.5 to each element of the matrix thanks to R sugar) to every element (here matrices) of the list `matList` and returns the resulting list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the commas that separate your variables. R syntax does not allow you to do it. Write it this way:

```
if (a && b && c && d == 0){
    a=a+0.5
    b=b+0.5
    c=c+0.5
    d=d+0.5
}
```

Another problem is that the behaviour you described does not match with your code. If you write && it means and, not or. If you want to check if each element is equal to 0, you should write the following:

Modified based on Rodrigo's comment, the correct code would be:

```
if (0 %in% c(a,b,c,d)){
    a=a+0.5
    b=b+0.5
    c=c+0.5
    d=d+0.5
}
```

Comment: if (a == 0 | b == 0 | c == 0 | d == 0)

Comment: This is no C++, so I think you can use | instead of ||. Or you could also use if (0 %in% c(a,b,c,d)), but you better avoid calling any variable "c", because that's a very used predefined function.

Comment: I have changed, a,b,c,d to n11, n12, n21, n22. Doing the above has given me a warning message `Warning message:
In if (n11 == 0 | n12 == 0 | n21 == 0 | n22 == 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo, the `(0 %in% c(a,b,c,d))` worked for me and is nice and neat

Comment: You warning means your values are vectors, use `all(n11 == 0)`. `|` and `&` are used to compare each term of the vectors and return a boolean vector while `||` and `&&` compare simple booleans

Comment: I have added an edit to the question. Would anybody be able to give me a hand on the second part?

Comment: @Math Yes I think that point is related to my second question which I have just added in.